# File download and save locally windows phone

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage

I m saving image into local folder for my windows phone application

```
var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder 

var photoFile = localFolder.CreateFileAsync(("mani"),
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

I m saving file without extension while save into locally for security reason and avoid other apps to view.

When i search google i got this api for launch default apps for file

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(photoFile);
```

But my local file dont have extension so i can't use this Api for default application launch could you please guide me alternative solution for this

Thanks,

Comment: while creating the file, you can use a dummy extension. and while reading it replace the dummy extension with correct extension format..

Comment: @Roy could you explain some what more, once i read like once i launch how can i revert the extension again